# How to Block the account When Username and password are Wrong

Tags: java, android

My Requirement is using count.when we press the button three times i want to appear toast message as Blocked ??please any one can show the code or condition.Any Error in Programming?

```
public void empbtn(View v) {
       EditText et11,et22;
        int counter = 3;
        int i;
        String unames[] = {"Anil","Ramesh","Khaja"};
        String passwds[] = {"anil","ramesh","khaja"};
        et11 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.empname);
        et22 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.emppass);
        String uname = et11.getText().toString();
        String pass = et22.getText().toString();
        if(uname.equals(""))
        {
            et11.setError("PLS ENTER NAME");
        }
      else if (pass.equals(passwds)) 
       {
        //et22.setError("pls enter password");
        Toast.makeText(main.this, "valid", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } 
     else {
        counter++;
        if (counter > 3) 
          {
            Toast.makeText(main.this, "blocked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else {
            for (i = 0; i < unames.length; i++) {
                if (uname.equals(unames[i]) && pass.equals(passwds[i])) {
                    setContentView(R.layout.home);
                    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.names);
                    tv.setText(uname);
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (i == unames.length) {
                Toast.makeText(main.this, "INVALID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put a boolean as a flag to know when is valid:

```
boolean isValid = false;

for (i = 0; i < unames.length; i++) {
            if (uname.equals(unames[i]) && pass.equals(passwds[i])) {
                setContentView(R.layout.home);
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.names);
                tv.setText(uname);
                isValid=true
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!isValid) {
            Toast.makeText(main.this, "INVALID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

**EDIT**

Try with this:

```
    if (i == unames.length-1) {
        Toast.makeText(main.this, "INVALID", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: i want condition sir using if statement

Comment: do you know that i value is going to be 2 in your code and unames.length is 3? try with unames.length-1.

Comment: Sir I Want Condition For Increasing Count.See my code once andtell me once what is the error?